# Scroll With Curve Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

In my app there is a menu which will be a scroll of Labels. I would like them to scroll vertically BUT on a arc. Here is an example:

[image: Demo Image]

http://s777.photobucket.com/user/appbeast/media/Applets-Favorites.mp4.html

I have created a demo, but its working on dragging up and down. not working while scrolling. I am sharing my demo code also. [Demo Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ta0hnslyr2tg7o2/scroller.zip?dl=0)

Any help will be appreciable guys.

Answer (score 1):

Have you take a look at this tutorial? [Rotating wheel control](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit)

Maybe yours is a special case

Answer (score 0):

better use collection view or tableview...  and then transform cell according to visible index to give the effect of scroll... 
https://github.com/bharath2020/UITableViewTricks

Answer (score 0):

One of Apple's WWDC lectures, I think this one: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/235/ Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques covers using a UIScrollview's gesture recognizers in your own views to get the same touch and deceleration behavior that users have come to expect. The example had views moving in an arc, but it was an OpenGL 3D arc, like a carnival carousel.